# When placing a Post on a wall the description goes missing

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

When trying to post a message on a friends wall for a logged in facebook user i am running into an issue where the post displays fine except for the description. The Description text is quite straight forward, not very long and does not contain any links so i don't see what could be causing this. The code, simplified, looks like this (it's python but you should get the idea if your using PHP or JS yourself i think):

```
description = "With Chummee you can send real-life gifts to your Facebook and Twitter friends. Or you can treat yourself!"

response = api.post(path = '%s/feed' % facebook_id,
        message = message, # shows up fine
        name = link_name, # this too
        link = pickup_url, # url works
        picture = wall_photo, # yup still no problem
        caption = 'chummee.com', # nice caption
        description = description, # <--- not showing this, see var above
        type = 'link' # adding this, does not seem to do anything though
)
```

Anybody know what could be causing description not to show? Is there a character limit that's not in the docs?

**edit:** this is now working as advertised!

Comment: I can't post messages yet else i'd show you a screenshot

Comment: have you tried putting some small test string in your description instead? e.g. `description = 'test',` I'm not familiar with python but it looks similar to the way it's done in PHP and JS so it might just be the string itself causing this to be blank. Another option is to remove the description parameter entirely and let facebook populate it from the link?

Comment: @martincarlin87 you were right. this particular text is not accepted. no idea why but with description = 'test' it works. I'll try some different wordings and try and figure out whether it's length or something else...

Comment: Allright, so i started adding more of the original text until it was back to the original and now it's working like a charm... Hard to tell if i messed up in earlier tests or whether Facebook changed something but i'm going to assume i messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description field is scraped from the og:description field on the "pickup_url".  This is done by Facebook when you create the link post, so the description field is pretty much read-only.

My attempts to set it through the API using the Graph Explorer were unsuccessful.

Comment: yeah this would work too i think, i'll mark this as a correct answer although the original setup seems to work now as well.